# Is compile-time constant expression evaluation ever required by the C standard?

Tags: c, standards, constantfolding

For example, is

```
static int a[1+1];
```

valid standard C? For some or all versions of the standard?

I'm not interested in whether compilers can handle it, but whether it is part of standard C.

Comment: The title does not seem to match the question, constant folding is an optimization technique and is definitely not required by the standard but is allowed. While `1+1` is a constant expression and it's properties are defined in the standard. It seems like your question is about constant expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C11, §6.6:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

So yes, simple constant folding is mandatory and this snippet is valid standard C.

Comment: Thanks! Was this the case in older versions of the standard?

Comment: @MikeGraham: I don't have an older version of the Standard handy, but it seems even [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tby3xex3(v=vs.80).aspx) uses this definition, which suggests it was present in C89.

Comment: @MikeGraham the C89 standard appears to have all the relevant parts present, so yes.

Comment: It says "can", not "must". It is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

The standard explicitly defines this.

Array declarators, 6.7.5.2 (C99):

> In addition to optional type qualiﬁers and the keyword static, the [
>   and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression
>   (which speciﬁes the size of an array), the expression shall have an
>   integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero.